# Implementing a pipeline corresponding to a set of instructions

Tags: assembly, pipeline

We are given this set of instructions:

```
1000  Add       R3, R2, #20
1004  Subtract  R5, R4, #3
1008  And       R6, R4, #0x3A
1012  Add       R7, R2, R4
```

and told that initially, registers `R2` and `R4` contain `2000` and `50`. We are dealing with a 5-stage pipeline where the first instruction is fetched in clock cycle 1, and the remaining instructions are fetched in successive cycles.

We are to draw the pipeline and describe the operation being performed by each pipeline stage during clock cycles 1 through 8. I am confused on what is meant by describing the operation being performed. Does that mean the Add instruction vs the Subtract instruction?

Here is my pipeline:

```
Clock Cycle           1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
Add R3, R2, #20       F  D  E  M  W
Subtract R5, R4, #3      F  D  E  M  W
And R6, R4, #0x3A           F  D  E  M  W
Add R7, R2, R4                 F  D  E  M  W
```

Or does this mean for instance in cycle 1 we are fetching the address `1000` and in cycle 2 we are loading the value into `R2` and reading in the Immediate value while fetching the address `1004` for the new instruction. Cycle 3 we evaluate `R2 + #20` while getting the value in `R4` and the immediate while fetching the address 1008. Cycle 4... so on and so fourth.

The other part of the question I am not sure about is where it says to describe the contents of registers IR, PC, RA, RB, RY, RZ in the pipeline during cycles 2 through 8. RA, RB, RY, RZ are pipeline registers.